# Disable and enable watches in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a watch on a data object:

```
$scope.$watch('data', function(after, before) {
    $scope.saveData();
}, true);
```

I also have a modal that pops up to edit some of the data object's properties above. However, if I edit any properties through this modal, but decide to 'cancel', it still saves the edited property.

Is there a way to disable that watch when the modal pops up?

Comment: Out of your question. I will suggest to use temp model to solve your problem rather than enable or disable the watch.

Comment: yes, passing a copy data to the modal would be much cleaner. but without knowing all the code, it is hard to guess if this would help

Answer (score 4):

$watch returns a function. if you call it you remove your watcher

[angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope), scroll down to $watch and take a look at the return value

```
var myWatcher = $scope.$watch('data', function(after, before) {
   $scope.saveData();
}, true);

myWatcher(); // removes your watcher
```

**EDIT**:
with [angular-ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) you could pass the deregistration function to the modal controller. modified example from the [docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal):

```
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return {
            data: data
            myWatcher: myWatcher // you can call items.myWatcher() in your modal controller
          };
        }
      }
    });
```

but i am not aware of a simple method (function call or similar) to re-enable the watcher. you will have to set it again.

```
    modalInstance.result.then(function (data) {
      $scope.data = data;
        }, function () {
          // callback for cancel, here you could re-apply the watcher
    });
```

Comment: So do I call it from the modal controller? How do I re-enable the watch?

Comment: @user3330014 are you using the angular-ui-bootstrap modal?

Comment: Yes, angular-ui-bootstrap

Comment: @user3330014 hope i could help, i need some sleep ;) good luck!